# changing huffman tree by adding k times the appearances of each letter in the string

Tags: string, huffman-code

Suppose I have a string , and I increase the string by  adding k times the appearances of each letter of that string (suppose we have the original string aabbbcc, and k=1, then the new string after the change will be aaabbbbccc) - Is this may cause changes in the huffman tree of that string?

I try to find an expample of of a string which such change happens by changing the string as written above, but so far I have failed.

Comment: could anyone help please?

Comment: Still not clear. "Adding k times"? So if a given letter appears _n_ times, is the resulting frequency "adding k times n", resulting in a frequency of _(k+1)n_, or is it adding "that letter k times", resulting in a frequency of _k+n_?

Comment: @MarkAdler, suppose we have the original string aabbbcc, and k=1, then the new string will be aaabbbbccc.

Comment: Ok. That's clear now. While in general the Huffman code lengths will change, note that for the specific example you give, the resulting Huffman code lengths will be exactly the same, since there is only one possible Huffman code for three symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If by "increase" you mean *multiply* by k, then no, the relative frequencies of the symbols don't change and the resulting Huffman code will not change. If by "increase" you mean *add* k, then if the original string did not have a equal frequencies for the symbols, then the relative frequencies would change, and it is likely that the Huffman code would change. (Not certain, since you could have been close to having equal frequencies.)

*Update:*

From the comments, you mean *adding* k occurrences. So yes, the Huffman code can change, if you're not already close to a flat distribution. It's easy to see that as k gets larger, you approach a flat distribution, as the original frequencies become insignificant compared to k.